# Comb and hair, is that an example for ionic boding?

Tags: atoms

As i understand, when brushing hair, some electron transfer from hair to the comb. Thus, make the comb have different charged from hair and they attract each other.
It's look likely what i have learn from school about ionic bond. One electron from Na is transfer to F and so we have NaF . Isn't it ???

Answer (score 2):

No, not at all. It is an example for *triboelectric charging*. A mechanical example for this type of electrostatic generators would be a **Van de Graaff generator**.

But all this has nothing to do with ionic bonds.